# System.Drawing.Font to reflect CSS Font

Tags: c#, css, fonts

I'm creating some images of text in code that need to reflect a CSS Font as closely as possible.  The CSS class looks like this:

```
.font
{
      letter-spacing: -0.7px;
      font-family: segoe wp,segoe ui,verdana,arial,helvetica,sans-serif;
      font-size: 1.15em;
      padding: 10px;
}
```

My image code looks like this:

```
using (var helper = new Bitmap(1, 1))
using (var gHelper = Graphics.FromImage(helper))
using (var font = new Font("Segoe WP", 1.15f, GraphicsUnit.Point))
using (var brush = new SolidBrush(Color.White))
{
    var size = gHelper.MeasureString(concept, font);

    using (var image = new Bitmap((int)size.Width + _padding, (int)size.Height + _padding))
    {
        using (var g = Graphics.FromImage(image))
        {
            g.Clear(Color.Black);
            g.DrawString(concept, font, brush, (float)_padding / 2, (float)_padding / 2);
        }

        var converter = new ImageConverter();
        var b = (byte[])converter.ConvertTo(image, typeof(byte[]));

        return File(b, _contentType);
    }
}
```

The images that are being produced by this code are VERY small.

The letter spacing I'm guessing will require that I make a loop and draw each letter individually, but how do I work with EMs inside of C#?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my opinion you can't work with EMs, because they're not fixed.
Read this part (extracted from http://webdesign.about.com/od/typemeasurements/qt/how-big-is-an-em.htm):

> **But How Big is an Em?**
>   According to the W3C an em:   "is equal to the
>   computed value of the 'font-size' property of the element on which it
>   is used. The exception is when 'em' occurs in the value of the
>   'font-size' property itself, in which case it refers to the font size
>   of the parent element." In other words, ems don't have an absolute
>   size. They take on their size values based on where they are. For most
>   Web designers, this means that they are in a Web browser, so a font
>   that is 1em tall is exactly the same size as the default font size for
>   that browser.
>
> **But how tall is the default size?**
>   There is no way to be 100% certain,
>   as customers can change their default font size in their browsers, but
>   since most people don't you can assume that most browsers have a
>   default font size of 16px. So most of the time 1em = 16px.

So you can try:

```
using (var font = new Font("Segoe WP", 16 * 1.15f, GraphicsUnit.Point))
```

knowing from the very beginning that this is only an approximation!!

Answer (score 1):

`using (var font = new Font("Segoe WP", 1.15f, GraphicsUnit.Point))`

Point != Em.

IIRC, em is just a ratio from the default font.

Answer (score 0):

Your graphics object assumes that you are drawing to the screen with a low resolution. Create a new graphics object and define a more appropriate resolution

```
Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(2000, 500);
bmp.SetResolution(300, 300); 
Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
// render your text.
```

You could also use System.Drawing.TextRenderer, which gives good results.